# Azure App Service Owin Instagram and other Auth providers

Tags: .net, azure, oauth, owin, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Ive just upgraded my old Azure mobile services app which had various other auth methods other than the facebook, google, twitter etc..

I think it owin 2.01.

They looked like this :

So implemented Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security.LoginProvider:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
        ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();
        options.PushAuthorization = AuthorizationLevel.User;
        options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(FacebookLoginProvider));
        options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(InstaLoginProvider));
        options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(TwitterLoginProvider));

        // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));

        // Set default and null value handling to "Include" for Json Serializer
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;

        Database.SetInitializer(new app_name_mobile_appInitializer());
    }
```

}

Provider implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using app_name_mobile_appService.DataObjects;
using app_name_mobile_appService.Models;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Owin;
using Owin.Security.Providers.Instagram;
using System.Linq;

namespace app_name_mobile_appService.Auth.ExtraLogins.Instagram
{
    public class InstaLoginProvider : LoginProvider
    {
        internal const string ProviderName = "Instagram";

        public InstaLoginProvider(IServiceTokenHandler tokenHandler)
            : base(tokenHandler)
        {
        }

        public override string Name
        {
            get { return ProviderName; }
        }

        public override void ConfigureMiddleware(IAppBuilder appBuilder,
            ServiceSettingsDictionary settings)
        {
            InstagramAuthenticationOptions options = new InstagramAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = settings["InstagramClientId"],
                ClientSecret = settings["InstagramClientSecret"],
                AuthenticationType = this.Name,
                Provider = new InstaLoginAuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                    {
                        ben_coomber_mobile_appContext mainContext = new app_name_mobile_appContext();

                        Account account = mainContext.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserIdWithProvider == context.Id);

                        if (account == null)
                        {
                            Account newAccount = new Account
                            {
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                Username = context.UserName,
                                InstagramToken = context.AccessToken,
                                UserIdWithProvider = context.Id,
                                ProviderType = "instagram"
                            };
                            mainContext.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
                            mainContext.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            };
            options.Scope.Add("likes");
            options.Scope.Add("comments");
            appBuilder.UseInstagramInAuthentication(options);
        }

        public override ProviderCredentials CreateCredentials(
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
        {
            Claim name = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            Claim providerAccessToken = claimsIdentity
                .FindFirst(ServiceClaimTypes.ProviderAccessToken);

            InstaCredentials credentials = new InstaCredentials()
            {
                UserId = this.TokenHandler.CreateUserId(this.Name, name != null ?
                    name.Value : null),
                AccessToken = providerAccessToken != null ?
                    providerAccessToken.Value : null
            };

            return credentials;
        }

        public override ProviderCredentials ParseCredentials(JObject serialized)
        {
            return serialized.ToObject<InstaCredentials>();
        }
    }
}
```

InstagramAuthenticationProvider implementation:

```
 using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security;
using Owin.Security.Providers.Instagram.Provider;

namespace app_name_mobile_appService.Auth.ExtraLogins.Instagram
{
    public class InstaLoginAuthenticationProvider :InstagramAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task Authenticated(InstagramAuthenticatedContext context)
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(
                new Claim(ServiceClaimTypes.ProviderAccessToken, context.AccessToken));
            return base.Authenticated(context);
        }
    }
}
```

ProviderCredentials implementation:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security;

namespace app_name_mobile_appService.Auth.ExtraLogins.Instagram
{
    public class InstaCredentials : ProviderCredentials
    {
        public InstaCredentials()
            : base(InstaLoginProvider.ProviderName)
        {
        }

        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So whats the correct way to do this using the newer stuff in the Azure App Service?

Im ashumming its some libs and extra things added here but i cant find any docs any where (would be helpful just ot know where docs are):

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Config;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ben_coomber_mobile_appService.OwinStartUp))]

namespace app_name_mobile_appService
{
    public class OwinStartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

            app.UseWebApi(config);

            AppServiceAuthenticationOptions options = new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions();

            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(options);
        }
    }
}
```

any help appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I assume that you provide three methods (Facebook, Instagram,Twitter) for Authentication. And you have implemented LoginProvider for Instagram by yourself in your old Azure mobile services app.

From [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/), we could find that:

> App Service supports five identity providers out of the box: Azure Active Directory, Facebook, Google, Microsoft Account, and Twitter. To expand the built-in support, you can integrate another identity provider or [your own custom identity solution](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#custom-auth).

For using `IAppBuilder.UseAppServiceAuthentication`, you could try to follow this official [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#custom-auth) and this sample [azure-mobile-apps-net-server](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/tree/master/samples/SampleApp).

Comment: Yes you have understood correctly, the application i have created pulls in feeds from twitter, facebook,instagram and a few others. from these feeds previously the user can sign in (and store tokens) so that the user can interact with each feed using their various api's. I have followed the tutorial you suggested to implement custom auth for signing into the app its self but cant get instagram to work at all using the owin.security.instgram libs like before :(